# What does AS followed by some queries mean at SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know `AS` is used to create an alias name in SQL. I know `with` is used if you want to save results of intermediate query or create a temp table. For example, something like the following:

```
with new_table as
(select * from order where order.id is Not NULL)
```

So the above query lets you reuse the new_table in another query. However what if you do not include with and write the following:

```
new_value as
(
  select
   A as Age,
   W as weight
  from
    order 
)
```

The as inside the select are creating the alias but what does the `new_value as` do?

it is different than `with new_value as`  ?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - they are completely different products... please ensure you tag it correctly. Syntax is invalid for SQL Server anyway.

Comment: BTW `WITH` (which is a Common Table Expression) doesn't save anything, its similar to a sub-query in that it allows you to structure your query in a more readable way.

Comment: Wait using with can't you create a temporary table or value for the query and use that name for other subsequent queries?

Comment: @DaleK it is updated.

Comment: Does that second example work in your DMBS? Normally for CTEs I would expect the first CTE defined to start with a `WITH` and then subsequent ones not to (they are part of the same `WITH`). I wouldn't expect no `WITH` at all.

Comment: How do you know recognize they are part of the same With or not?

Comment: A normal query can have a comma-separated list of CTEs followed by the main (for lack of a better word) query that uses them... something like `WITH mycte1 AS (...), mycte2 AS (...), mycte3 AS (...) SELECT * FROM mycte3....` The `WITH` there is for all the common table expressions.

Comment: `new_value as ()` as written is just a syntax error.

Comment: @EdmCoff, can you write your comment as an answer, I think you are right. Can you elaborate also on your answer when you put comma between with and other queries, this mean that you are  adding with without the comma?

Comment: I'm curious if you have considered reading the documentation on the `WITH` syntax in the MySQL manual. It will probably answer most of your questions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: @user59419 I've posted my comment as an answer. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single query, there is one `WITH` that can apply to multiple comma-separated CTEs. The CTEs are then followed by the main part of the query that can reference them.

For example,

```
WITH
 mycte1 AS
  (SELECT 1 as a),
 mycte2 AS
  (SELECT 1 as b),
 mycte3 AS
  (SELECT * FROM mycte1 INNER JOIN mycte2 ON a=b)
SELECT *
FROM mycte3
```

The CTE `mycte1` isn't special just because it follows the `WITH`. The `WITH` is for all 3 CTEs (`mycte1`, `mycte2`, and `mycte3`).

Note that even though the order of the CTEs matters in this case (`mycte3` needs to be defined after `mycte1` and `mycte2` since it references them), that's not because any of the CTEs is specially linked to the `WITH`.

You cannot write CTEs without the `WITH`.

You can read more in the [documentation for CTEs/WITH.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)